# How to call a method in Android from onCreate

Tags: android, methods, parameters, oncreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chustilla();}


public void chustilla (View v){ //Do anything }
```

When I compile it gives me a problem in the parameter of chustilla(). What can I do to call this method from onCreate?

PD: If I put "this" or "null" inside the brackets it doesn't work aswell

Answer (score 2):

`chustilla(View)` requires a `View` reference to be passed as a parameter so it won't work if you don't pass a `View` reference to it. According to what is done in`chustilla(View)` (best known to you) you can pass it a `View` from the layout (Also, best known to you).

Answer (score 1):

Your method `public void chustilla (View v)` expects to be passed a `View` object. But in `onCreate()` You simply call `chustilla()`. You need pass it a view object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chustilla(a);
}


public void chustilla (Int a)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chustilla();
}


public void chustilla ()
{
    //Do anything 
}
```

Comment: what if chustilla () has two or three parameters, how to call this on onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

or use this for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String s;
    chustilla(s);
}


public void chustilla (String v)
{ //write code here }
```

Comment: But what if `//Do anything` in @user3481906's code necessarily requires a `View`?

Comment: v is a string no View

Comment: That's what I am saying @user3481694. What if @user3481906's code necessarily requires a `View` to be passed as a parameter to `chustilla()`

Answer (score -1):

example parameter "new View(this)" :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chustilla(new View(this));}


public void chustilla (View v){ //Do anything }
```